# AngularJS 1.5+ Bind a trancluded expression to child component controller

Tags: angularjs

I have to do a strange thing and I struggle with it for a long time: How to "freeze" a transcluded expression to be bound in a specific **child** component instead of defaulting behavior which is binding to the current controller? So with the code like this:

```
<parent>
    <child>{{childCtrl.childValue}}</child>
</parent>
```

I'd like to bind the expression to a controller of **child** component to show its data.

Components look like this:

```
.component('parent',{
    template: `<p ng-transclude></p>`,
    transclude: true
})

.component('child',{
    template: `
    <li>expression hard coded: <b>{{childCtrl.childValue}}</b>
    <li>expression value from transclusion: <b><span ng-transclude></span></b>`,

    transclude: true,
    controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
    controller: function() {
        this.childValue = 'working!'
    }
})
```

There's no problem in injecting some passive HTML but I really need to do it with expressions also. [Here's the fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/eQ5bAH92h6GbEhnrxArb?p=preview), I believe there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

**First :** I dont think ng-transclude is the way to go because it compiles whatever you want to transclude using the outer controller scope.

**Second :** With the Angularjs way of thinking (Or even the component way of thinking), it doesn't make sense to access a component's model/scope from outside the component itself, and trying to do so breaks the encapsulation principle and the single responsibility principle, the outer component shouldn't tell the inner component what to with its model. so i'd like to ask, is it really the way you need to do things ? is it the best design ? do you have a specific real use case for this ?

What you can do instead is configure which value you want to display, [see this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/US4qF8m0bkIuezkDN0kT?p=preview)

```
.component('parent',{
    template: `
    <p ng-transclude></p>`,
    transclude: true
})

.component('child',{
  bindings: {
    displayedAttribute: "@"
  },
    template: `
    <li>expression hard coded: <b>{{childCtrl.childValue}}</b>
    <li>expression with configured value: <b>{{childCtrl[childCtrl.displayedAttribute]}}</b>`,

    transclude: true,
    controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
    controller: function($compile, $scope) {
        this.childValue = 'working!'
        this.anotherChildValue= 'also working!'
    }
})
```